# Cheaper, Faster, Better Housing

Tags: science-based, construction, robots

The year is 2026 and there's angry talk of repealing old free-trade deals as politicians claim jobs are being destroyed by foreign competition. That is, Chinese and Indian construction companies are going bankrupt in their thousands against invading low-cost companies from the United States.

Due to unexpectedly enlightened, pro-business leadership, good old American grit and ingenuity, and a massive increase in H1B visas for foreign PhDs, companies that were merely startups 5 year prior are now trillion-dollar concerns and are revolutionizing the construction business with radically high-tech construction methods driving durability up, quality up, and prices way way down.

The revolution is driven by a set of dual technological breakthroughs, respectively in **industrial robotics**, with autonomous heavy-duty mobile industrial plant assemblers replacing 95% of construction labor, and in **materials science**, with a relatively cheap and reliable way to build nonflamable high-strength long fibers in vast quantities, with a color range dialable from transparent through the entire rainbow. Pipes and even powerlines can be weaved in, as it were, during the automated construction process.

The story is from the perspective of an American business-man on Indian origin in India, where he's dealing with the regulation Raj and hostile construction workers and companies. He's a salesman, not an engineer, but it would help the story to make him sound like he knows a bit about what he's talking about.

Let's take a standard single-family home (let's say a tad below today's U.S. median, 2200 sq. ft space ~ 200 sq. meters).

- **How cheap would it have to be to build to drive low-cost labor using standard materials (cement, bamboo, whatever) out of business?** (Answers may ignore the cost of land if it makes it easier, just focus the build)
- **How cheap could it conceivably get?** As in, is it plausible to have a house that size cost the manufacturer \$100, \$1,000 or \$10,000 to build from the ground up?

Note: To the untrained eye, it might look like there are 2 questions above, but I actually care about the entepreneur's **profit margin**, so it's really just one question...

Comment: So we are to assume that a fleet of high tech robots are hands down more cost effective than a bunch of workers being paid a few dollars a day?And also to research profit margins in the Indian construction industry?

Comment: Robotics and 3d Printing are both cool, but nothing beats genetics!  Imagine a fast growing GMO tree which grows into the framing for a house, complete with plumbing.  Now add some GMO spiders which weave waterproof walls and ceiling.  Line the interior with a GMO bio-luminescent fungus for illumination and put another on the roof to serve as a living solar panel.  The nice part of using life to create housing is that the house can grow along with the needs of its occupants.  "We holding off on having another baby until the new rooms bloom."

Comment: @HenryTaylor  *until the new rooms bloom.* )) nice  - but I guess they will wait for loooong looong time until it happens. 0.01km^2 of forest produces about 4 tonnes of material per year, I guess their home takes way less then 0.01km^2 of a territory and baby room may easily need 4 tonnes of material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally possible.  Do it right now.

Mass produce **special trucks**.  Like a Transformer in that many flat surfaces **unfold** out of it, and like a self-driving car in that it laser positions itself precisely, relative to other trucks and a little radio transmitter set in the ground.  5-10 of these trucks are driven to a build site and unfold, **creating the forms for concrete walls**.  Old fashioned humans scurry around on catwalks dropping in prefab pipe and electrical conduit sections, which magnets in the trucks grab and hold in correct position.  Embedded tech helps align and confirm alignment.

Dozens of sets of these trucks are active in any development at any time.  (Note that each set of trucks can build a different floor plan of house).  They are served by two **throw-up redi-mix concrete plants**, similar to those used at freeway construction sites. Human or robotic driven trucks continuously haul concrete out to whichever build site is ready for pour.  The concrete is mixed with high-tech fiber, which replaces reinforcing rod.

As soon as concrete cure allows, the trucks fold up, drive out of intentionally designed holes, and transit to the next build site, rinse wash repeat.

If a second floor is involved, wait until the concrete has cured to full strength and do the same thing again, with roving ramp trucks helping the truck get to the 2nd floor.

Roofs are either concrete and part of the pour, or are **prefab** truss and panel modules that snap together fast, largely by robots, again with **embedded tech helping with positioning.**

The limiting factor is the mold trucks sitting there waiting for concrete cure.

Edit: *Alternate wall method*: The bulk of the robotics is in the factory, building prefab wall "forms" with pipes/conduits embedded.  Outer wall is 6" foam, inner is nailable and paintable.  Walls interlock with embedded tech to assure alignment and bracing, may be backstopped with much simpler versions of above trucks.  After the concrete pour, forms are [left there permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulating_concrete_form).  These buildings have a lot of thermal mass, which would facilitate a [passive solar design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_solar_building_design), greatly cutting HVAC costs.  No limit to floorplans.  It could even be custom, and the resident himself could design it using software which corrals him into what the robots can build.

Interior walls would be non-load-bearing and prefab modules, built 2" shorter than the ceiling height, aligned and jacked. Bottom space covered with kickboard.

Robots would slap in a lot of other modules, like windows, door assemblies, etc. HVAC and water heater drops in as a module.  Large, unwieldy bath and kitchen parts snap in as modules, and they are interchangeable.

And a prefab electrical service panel (breaker box).   Its upper section has the meter, main breaker, 2 small breakers, 4 outlets and 2 LED lights (which are always available).  The lower section more resembles a normal electrical box, except removing the lower cover knocks out power.  This idiot-proofing is because...

...**The whole damn rest of the house is an IKEA kit.**

If we're building these houses for tigers, this doesn't work.  But if we're building for humans, we can harness the owner himself as **off-the-books free labor** to do the finishing work, just as IKEA already does.

If they really, really want to live in the house as-delivered, they will at least be dry.  But most likely they'll get sick of cooking in the utility room with a hotplate plugged into a panel outlet, crack the book and start snapping things together.  Or their kids will.  Or their neighbors will have a [house raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn_raising).

This also opens a free market, want a dishwasher, buy a "Maytag Luminant(tm) 4310 Dishwasher for Standard Kitchen Unit 3, 4, 7 or 13”.

When the entire development is built, the trucks and knock-down concrete plant drive to the next.  If it's a far distance, they drive to the nearest railhead and onto flat cars.  The railhead itself could become a commuter railroad.  Rail access would help anyway for bringing in concrete aggregates and the bulky prefab modules, and hauling [empty pallets](http://mhlnews.com/transportation-amp-distribution/automakers-build-returnable-systems-pallets) back to the factory - prefab module packaging can be made reusable.  Two humans can drive a 20,000 ton train.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel%C3%A1k - this was done in the past

Answer (score 7):

I'm basing my answer on the fact that you specifically asked if it is ***plausible*** "to have a house that size cost the manufacturer \$100, \$1,000 or \$10,000 to build from the ground up".

And my answer is **No.**

Your story stems from the assumption that automating every facet of constructing a building is going to save a massive amount of money. However, I don't think this is actually the case - especially not in the third world (I use the term loosely, but you know what I mean), as they enjoy the advantage of being bound by very few safety and workplace regulations, while benefiting from a massive pool of potential employees.

Those sorts of robots would probably be quite pricey. Furthermore, they work in environments which are intrinsically dangerous - a bunch of them are going to get knocked out of commission, or go haywire and cause some very expensive damage to the property.

Furthermore, you'll have to keep an eye out for viruses, hackers, or good ol' sabotage. I'm not saying that human workers are the superior choice! I'm simply trying to point out that robots are not necessarily a cheap alternative.

If, for example, you had dumped a bunch of raw materials into a field and *nanobots* assembled everything (going so far as to create concrete and other materials on the fly) then sure, there is no way anyone putting up buildings the good ol' fashioned way could compete.

However your approach is only superior in terms of (I'll assume) quality of construction, and perhaps the time frame in which it is built, not, in my opinion, cost of the "workforce".

In other words, the target market for these robots might be putting up very expensive, large projects, like the world's next super-sky-scrapper, not cheap income housing in India.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking at the wrong technology. 3D printing is cooler than robots, that's just a fact of nature.

Okay, maybe it's not really a fact. [There's that though](http://inhabitat.com/chinese-company-builds-3d-printed-villa-in-less-than-3-hours/). Villa? Pfft, what about [an apartment complex](http://www.cnet.com/news/worlds-first-3d-printed-apartment-building-constructed-in-china/)? Or a [flippin' bridge](http://3dprintingindustry.com/2015/10/16/construction-of-worlds-1st-3d-printed-bridge-begins-in-amsterdam/)? It's fast, it's cheap, it's safe, and at the very worst it beats living in a slum. You want to drive the price of construction down, don't look at robots, look at 3D printing.

In the example of the Chinese villa, the price is 400 to 480 USD/m². So for 2000 ft², which is 185.8 m², that's 74.3k to 89.2k USD of construction costs, in 10 days of time. Undoubtedly, you can do much cheaper than that, which is already pretty cheap considering the size.

I don't know about 10k for 185.8m², but it would say it's plausible that you could build a small city house for that price in ten years.

Comment: I think the difference between 3D printing and robotic construction is largely semantic.  A 3D printer is just a robot that builds an object inside it.

Comment: @IndigoFenix I agree with you, a 3D printer is a specialized case of a robot, but one that most people probably wouldn't identify as such hence the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

If we could engineer hexagonal or square bamboo, you could bring the price of lumber down by a lot.

but really mud bricks have always been cheap, in dry climates you can build from almost nothing but clay and straw and end up with a decent home. I can't give hard numbers on the price though.

But we have already figured a way to drastically reduce labor costs, prefabricated modular housing, built on a giant assembly line then transported to site in sections. maximum number of homes for lowest cost. Prices I have seen are around $65 a sqrft in the US.

They work becasue the raw material is moved in bulk to a central location that can be built for that purpose reducing cost of material. Your workers are under ideal conditions all the time and you are only transporting the finished material instead of everything including the workers as in normal construction.

If you want a futuristic feel automated airship delivery would be great again lower cost becasue it does not have to move the home in pieces, and are much more maneuverable than trucks.

Answer (score 0):

You can already build a house for a few thousands dollars in a third world country.

How do you think those people earning 100$ a month can afford a house?

You would need nano robots capable of transforming matter from any form into any other form and nearly unlimited renewable energy (fusion or solar) to reach that goal. That would be probably after 2100.

Comment: Fusion is not a renewable energy though.

Comment: @DoomedMind same as wind, solar and hydro is not renewable - because fusion is what happens in the Sun.

Comment: @MolbOrg no, solar, wind and hydro are renewable per definition. Fusion is not, since it consumes (irreversibly) fuel. Apart from that, fusion is the only one of those I named introducing extra energy to the cycle.

Comment: @DoomedMind "renewable energy - energy from a source that is not _depleted_ when used, such as wind or solar power." If you have source of fusion fuel with is not depleted when you use fuel you use - it will be as good as renewable. Jupiter is one of such sources, sun itself is one of such sources - they are pretty big.

Comment: @MolbOrg Both are inaccessible for the extraction of fusable fuel. Your definition is neither what is considered scientific consensus nor political consensus. Currently, Fusion is classified as a nuclear power source.

Comment: @DoomedMind I understand what you talking about, I'm just trying to be a moron.

Comment: @MolbOrg I know.

Comment: Their is enough hydrogen in the earths oceans to keep us supplied with a LOT of power for as long as the earth is habitable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cut of labor cost is questionable, depends on how expensive will be those robots and maintenance - and you can bet it will, not one will sell a thing worth millions for 10\$. Not the main problem trough.

Building materials are not for free, even dirt is not for free, at leasе not in all places, especially in quantities needed for building.

Real profit margin will be more that this businessman can build things faster, so if his company is an average size(employees, building workers are not counted) he can keep a bigger share of the market compared to his opponents.

Have faster turnover for the same amount of employees - it is not bad at all, a significant advantage against other companies, and more attractive for buyer especially if price is a bit lower and quality is higher.

For moving those robots-machines - energy is needed. Energy has to be transported. To move 1kg of bricks your machines and conventional machines use about the same amount of energy.

It makes sense if you have an excess of high-quality specialists, and have a low number of low-quality workers, but energy wise it may or may not be more efficient.

How about fair market tactics this machine needs only certified cement to work properly, or we do not guarantee it will work and you need to pay us for the repair in this case? (you will pay us anyway, but just to start talking) And this cement is prepared by 11 elf's, and they need very expensive pollen to work properly, which is made by a fairy and that is very expensive therefore we sell you that cement 10 times more expensive than usual cement as we pay most of that money to them. No, no, we can't prove this, it is our patented technology in general, but secret ingredient is not patented so we can't ...

I use that elf's just because, but there are a lot of legal ways to blow the cost, as pharmaceutics do.

So it is important to include the cost of construction materials, cost of energy, cost of equipment, cost of maintenance, the cost of developing new models of houses to build with this equipment, the cost to find all bugs in those projects because of upgraded equipment or upgraded software(all sorts of usual software and hardware problems we face with computer now, but with that house building equipment then), etc etc.

Even if you cut all costs, except building materials then the answer to:

- How cheap could it conceivably get? As in, is it plausible to have a house that size cost the manufacturer \$100, \$1,000 or \$10,000 to build from the ground up?

\$100, \$1000 - no.
\$10'000 - probably not, but depends. In my country, it will be about the bare minimum for a smaller than US house, with 0 cost for the work(DIY style), just for materials. Not sure about India.